# How to extend the ViewModel with a composed Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In a MVC project I have this simpel ViewModel I use to populate a table in the .cshtml. Each column is easily populated with properties from the device object.

I need to make a new column and populate it with a count. This count is crafted from the deviceId on the server.

I want to extend my ViewModel with a Count property. The count is crafted by each deviceId that's used to retrieve a list and then the count.

So my question is how do you design this "composed" ViewModel? I thought about wrapping it all in a private class but I don't know if that's the best practices.

ViewModel:

```
public class DeviceViewModel
{
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

.cshtml:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Version</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var device in Model.Devices)
        {
            <tr id="@device.ID">
                <td>@device.Name</td>
                <td>@device.Priority</td>
                <td>@device.Version</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I imagine the .cshtml to be something like this and don't know about the ViewModel:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var composedDevice in Model.ComposedDevices)
        {
            <tr id="@composedDevice.ID">
                <td>@composedDevice.Name</td>
                <td>@composedDevice.Priority</td>
                <td>@composedDevice.Version</td>
                <td>@composedDevice.Count</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here, can you perhaps give an example?

Comment: Do you mean you would like a `GroupBy` on your devices, grouped by Id?

Comment: @device.Name, @device.Priority and @device.Version is all something i can get directly from the device object. I need to extend with a new column in the table, with some data NOT hanging on the `device` object. How do I do that?

Comment: Why can't you add `Count` to `Device`? Also, you can use `@foreach(...){}`

Comment: I can't change in the `Device` nor would I.

Comment: How about an extension method on `Device`?

Comment: Use a view model with an `int Count` property. Your current `DeviceViewModel` is not really a view model - you may as well just pass `IEnumerable<Device>` to the view.

Comment: I don't really understand why you can't add a property to `Device` unless it's not a view model itself. If so, then create a model with a `Count` property.

Comment: The idea of a view model is to have class **specifically for your view**. It is very handy to have such a class, and the use of metadata attributes encourages that (for example, Password is `[Required]` in log in page, optional in update details page). One of the down side is that you duplicate a lot of the properties, but you do gain per-view flexibility.

Comment: @Kobi I know that. That's the fine part with MVC.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need a count _for each_ of the device in the list. That's the tricky part m8.

Comment: Which is why you need a view model - `public class DeviceVM` with properties for `ID`, `Name`, `Priority`, `Version` **and** `Count` and then pass `IEnumerable<DeviceVM>` to the view

Comment: Ahh I think I get it now. Your VM doesn't contains the list, just the Properties that descripts the VM. And then somewhere in the controller i build or return and IEnumerable<DeviceVM> insead. I will give it a try!